# Passively load a monitoring shared object into an Oracle process

Tags: oracle, security, audit, plugins

I'm trying to load my own code, which should add some security features to my environment, into each oracle BEQ dedicated process.

The reason I'm posting this on this platform, is that I hope there is some DBA hack to trick Oracle to load my shared object when a new instance of oracle starts to run.

I have found out about [external_libraries](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A64702_01/doc/server.805/a58236/10_procs.htm) that in first glance seemed to fit, but after investigating how it works, I'm have found out that the library is being loaded into another external process and the loading will only happen on triggering a specific external function.

I know DB2 has an option to load external plugins to add functionality to the database (e.g [1](https://www.ibm.com/support/producthub/db2/docs/content/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.sec.doc/doc/c0060264.html), [2](https://www.ibm.com/support/producthub/db2/docs/content/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.sec.doc/doc/c0012013.html) and [3](https://www.ibm.com/support/producthub/db2/docs/content/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.sec.doc/doc/c0011970.html)) - this would fulfill my needs. - Again, I'm not intrested in the actual logic behind the plugin, all I want is the oracle to pull/load me passively into it's memory space when it starts.

Can you think of anything?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Using LD_PRELOAD to implement a hidden trojan in an oracle database](https://mahmoudhatem.wordpress.com/2018/06/13/using-ld_preload-to-implement-a-hidden-trojan-in-an-oracle-database/)

You can also follow the links there. Like this one: https://yurichev.com/writings/oracle.pdf

Comment: This PDF is awesome, I had no idea Oracle has this relink command. I'm also interested in other Oracle internal functions reverse engineering. Are you familiar with any resources?

Comment: Be aware that (if it matters) these kind of custom add-ons very likely will void the support agreement of any system that runs them. The Oracle license agreement generally prohibits modification or reverse engineering of their software.